# Instance does not boot after adding a GPU

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We're using GCE and we wanted to add a GPU to one of our instances.

I did the following steps:
* stopped the instance
* added a K80 GPU
* saved
* started the instance

And it does not start anymore. I've tried to start it up 4 times now, it failed all these times.
I have 3 error codes:

- Code: '-5246221063224473180'
- Code: '-3053251512212947706'
- Code: '-7047116650960579979'
- Code: '-8365157783958652779'

This may be related to the issue.

```
Machine type
n1-standard-4 (4 vCPUs, 15 GB memory)
CPU platform
Unknown CPU Platform
GPUs
1 x NVIDIA Tesla K80
```

The instance is in europe-west1-b

```
~$ gcloud compute zones describe europe-west1-b
availableCpuPlatforms:
- Intel Skylake
- Intel Broadwell
- Intel Haswell
- Intel Sandy Bridge
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the issue might be related to your cpu plataform type.
As per documentation [1] GPU devices are available to attach only to instances with the Broadwell CPU platform and a maximum of 64 vCPUs.
I suggest to create a new instance with the appropriate CPU.
You could achieve that by running the below command:

```
gcloud compute instances create example-instance --zone europe-west1-b --min-cpu-platform "Intel Broadwell" --machine-type "n1-standard-4"
```

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/#restrictions

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I think that may be the issue here. For now, it's back up without GPU and doing some computations. As soon as this is over, I'll switch it off and test with Broadwells.

Comment: Well, I just checked with at least Broadwell. It fails in the same manner.

Comment: Same with "at least Skylake". Cannot boot up with a GPU.

Comment: Would you post the serial port's logs ? This might help to troubleshoot your issue. As well as "gcloud compute instance [instance name] describe.